# How to display the Google sign in button in Java Desktop?

Tags: java, button, sign

This is my first question on this forum. The my doubt is really which I wrote in the title. I'm making a Java desktop application and I need to sign in with Google in my application. I need something like this:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/master/img/signin-button.png

I'm looking for the Google Client Api for Java for many days but I could not get anywhere. Someone can to say me how I do this in Java? I have already a project in Google Console.

**Edit**

I'm using JavaFX in my application.

Comment: This type of sign in is called OAuth (usually, OAuth 2). Now you know the name, search for it on Google. This question doesn't really fit the nature of this site.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for respond. I searched, but I didn't  find how to display the button or the permissions screen. If you can to help me I thank you, because I never did it and I'm looking for it for many days and I still can not do anything.

Comment: Ahh... First things first. You have to decide how to display anything on the screen. Is it a desktop app, mobile app, website? Then look around for the right "GUI toolkit" fitting your environment. Start doing some graphics, etc. etc. etc. Then you can worry about this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I forget this detail. Is a desktop Javafx application

Comment: It's really possible to make it? Or I'm trying impossible something?

Comment: Of course it is possible. I just didn't clearly understand your question. Do you just want to display the button without the sign in behaviour? Then you can put the picture in a javafx `Button`. The sign in itself is a totally different story. For this you need a Java OAuth 2 library, learn how to use it, and integrate it with your JavaFX application.

Comment: No, I want that the button call the permissions screen of the Google, I want to implement the sign in button just like the websites. I want to make something like this: https://youtu.be/Oy5F9h5JqEU in Javafx.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2

Comment: I'm seeing this same link and looking for OAuth 2 for many days but it don't this that I want. Do you could can to show me an example to make this screen?